# if attribute x = "something" do this

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following tables running, but I'm having a problem on a specific situation.

I have a network of soap dispensers, that I want to keep track of their current soap level. I'm counting the number of pumps (3 mililiters each) and doing `greatest(full_capacity - number_pumps * 3, 0)` as seen on the View table.

But my problem is: there is table maintenance, and one of the "descriptions" may be "refill". What I wanted was for when a `maintenance_description = "refill"` for the `number_pumps` in table records be set to 0 for that exact dispenser. Is is possible? I read about triggers, but couldn't really understand how to do this.

As a pratical example, lets say I have soap dispenser id 1 with a max capacity of 1000ml, I then count 300 pumps, so I know I have 100ml left. I then do a refill and want the number of pumps to get set to 0. Otherwise in the next use it will say I have 97ml available, when in reality I have 997ml because I already made a refill.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
create table dispenser(
    id_dispenser int not null auto_increment,
    localization_disp varchar(20) not null,
    full_capacity int not null,
    primary key (id_dispenser));

create table records(
    time_stamp  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    dispenser_id int not null,
    number_pumps int not null,
    battery_level float not null,
    primary key (dispenser_id,time_stamp));

create table maintenance(
    maintenance_id int not null auto_increment,
    maintenance_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    maintenance_description varchar(20) not null,
    dispenser_id int not null,
    primary key (maintenance_id));


CREATE VIEW left_capacity
AS
SELECT max(time_stamp) AS calendar,
       id_dispenser AS dispenser,
       full_capacity AS capacity,
       greatest(full_capacity - number_pumps * 3, 0) AS available
       FROM records r
            INNER JOIN dispenser d
                       ON d.id_disp = r.id_dispenser
       GROUP by id_dispenser;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.  It is. not really clear what the data looks like or what you want the results to look lilke.

Comment: Sorry, my database is all written in portuguese, I just translated the code above to english but my tables content is all in portuguese.

Comment: Sample data is typically not real data, just something simple to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a view with the amount remaining.  This would be the number pumps since the last refill, subject to your formula.

MySQL has had tricky issues with subqueries in views.  I think the following is view-safe for MySQL:

```
select d.*,
       (d.full_capacity -
        (select count(*) * 3
         from records r
         where r.id_dispenser = d.id_dispenser and
               r.time_stamp > (select max(m.maintenance_date)
                               from maintenance m
                               where m.id_dispenser = r.id_dispenser and
                                     m.maintenance_description = 'refill' 
                              )
        )
       ) as available
from dispenser d;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, but my maintenance_description could be something else like a change of battery, it't not always a refill.

I can add that and say where m.id_dispenser = r.id_dispenser and m.maintenance_description='refill' but then the count (*) won't make sense I guess. Available will always be my full_capacity.

Comment: @tawny_alexa . . . It should work with the "refill" filter.

Comment: I'm very thankfull for your answer but it doesn't work for what I want to do. I need to know the difference between the number_pumps on max date of records - number_pumps on the max date of refill.